# Chrome rises autofill input event after clicking the page only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autofill

fill the form, save values in Chrome for Mac, then reload page.
alert will show only after page is clicked,
why is that? How can I get input events fired right after
page load, not after click? Thank you
[link to reproduce the issue here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fp4cyghh/28/show/),
[this is source](https://jsfiddle.net/fp4cyghh/28/)
Code of the example below:

```
    <form action="https://test.de" method="POST" name="loginform">
    <input oninput="alert('text')" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
    <input oninput="alert('pass')" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <div class="log"></div>
    <script>document.querySelector("input").focus();</script>
```

Comment: hey, have you found out what causes the problem?